# Which Git merge strategy is better?

Tags: git, git-flow

I have a `master` branch and `development` branches per ticket.
What is the correct way to merge `dev` branch to `master`,

Merge updates from `master` to `dev`, resolve conflicts, merge `dev` to `master`

or

Merge `dev` to `master` and then resolve conflicts?

Comment: They lead to different results, so the proposed solutions aren't comparable.

Comment: The result expected to be a master branch with merged dev branch into it, so it can be deployed somewhere.

Comment: In that case, the second option sounds like it would do just fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I do is, in `Development branch`:

```
$ # work in development
```

When finished, commit changes in `development` and merge the branch:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge development
```

You can check [Branching Workflows](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Branching-Workflows) at git-scm.com

Answer (score 3):

Both of these two strategies are valid options, but lead to slightly different results and histories.  It really depends on the workflow that you using and how others may also be working on the same repository.

Have a look at [git-flow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow) which will provide a simple way to wrap up the creating and merging of each development/feature branch.

As a general rule I always do conflict resolution on the shortest lived branch in the merge, in your case the development branch.